# Stream Analytics

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

Is it possible to include more than one input source in stream analytics? I want to output different columns into the same output , however, it does not allow me to use the same output name.

This is the query I wrote: 
 with pg1 as( SELECT    count(*),id FROM   EventHub where id='1' group by id,TumblingWindow(hour,1) ), pg2 as( SELECT    count(*) ,id FROM EventHub      where id='2' group by id, TumblingWindow(hour,1) )  Select count(*) into PowerBiAlias from pg1 group  by TumblingWindow(hour,1) Select count(*) into PowerBiAlias from pg2 group  by TumblingWindow(hour,1)

Answer (score 2):

Try a union then select into the output:

```
with 
pg1 as(
 SELECT count(),id 
 FROM EventHub
 where id='1'
 group by id,TumblingWindow(hour,1) 
), 
pg2 as(
 SELECT count() ,id
 FROM EventHub
 where id='2'
 group by id, TumblingWindow(hour,1) 
),
UnionStep as (
 Select count() as cnt from pg1 group by TumblingWindow(hour,1) 
 Union All
 Select count() as cnt from pg2 group by TumblingWindow(hour,1)
)
Select *
Into PowerBiAlias
From UnionStep
```